# rename file to current date in one bash command

Tags: bash

How to do below in one bash command ? I mean rename file to current date

```
$ echo `date +"%m-%d-%y"`
01-14-16
$ mv backup1.tar 01-14-16
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
mv backup1.tar "$(date +"%m-%d-%y")"
```

`$(...)` is an alternative syntax to ``. This will first execute  `$(date +"%m-%d-%y")`, so that the command line really becomes `mv backup1.tar 01-14-16`.

Please note that it might be good to do some checking here, e.g. if the file already exists.